# Problems with strtotime() on remote server

Tags: php, server, remote-server

I am having trouble with strtotime working on the localhost, but not the remote server.

I am using the following code to parse the dates for the days in each week;

```
$monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday this week +'.$x.' week'));
$tuesday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('tuesday this week +'.$x.' week'));
$wednesday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('wednesday this week +'.$x.' week'));
$thursday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('thursday this week +'.$x.' week'));
$friday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('friday this week +'.$x.' week'));
$saturday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('saturday this week +'.$x.' week'));
$sunday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('sunday this week +'.$x.' week'));
```

This works correctly in localhost.

On the remote server it returns;

```
2018-10-22
2018-10-22
2018-10-22
2018-10-22
2018-10-22
2018-10-22
2018-10-28
```

So it is parsing the correct date for Monday and Sunday.  Every other day parses the same date as Monday.

Comment: Have you var dumped the strtotime segments individually to see what it returns?

Comment: What versions of PHP are you running? [There were several date-related bug fixes in v7.0.17](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.0.17), which appears to be the version in which this code starts working correctly. See https://3v4l.org/Bt0PT . In short, make sure you're developing and deploying to the same version.

Comment: Your "it returns" is the result of interpretation, that's not a good think if you the omit the expected output from your question. Please provide a [mcve] and the according output on both machines.

Comment: I dumped all the segments except Tuesday - which still parsed the date for Monday.

Comment: I tried changing each function to 'next week'.  This didn't change the issue with incorrect dates parsing for tuesday to saturday.

Comment: I would suggest using a php Library like Carbon :) it makes working with dates a lot easier :)

Answer (score 1):

The server was running php version 5.6.
The issue was resolved by installing version 7.1.